# Scraping Link with name of link

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrap the link with jsoup
[image]
Both link are exactly same but I want to fetch only second one any suggestion?

I tried this but its not working

```
 Element pagination2 = document3.select("div.pagination").first();
 Elements Link2 =pagination2.select("a.older");
```

Comment: atleast provide the html page with the inclosing div and pagination you are accessing here document3.select("div.pagination").first();

Comment: well it was https://github.com/apple/turicreate/commits/master?after=b7432a7e73c8efa0466e7b338f2717d392ba1f72+34

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple, this should look something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String url = "https://github.com/apple/turicreate/commits/master?after=b7432a7e73c8efa0466e7b338f2717d392ba1f72+34";
        final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        final Elements elements = doc.select("div.pagination a"); // get all "a" elements

        // get the second element via index
        final Element secondElement = elements.get(1);
        // get the href attribute (link)
        final String href = secondElement.attr("href");
        // get the text of second element
        final String older = secondElement.text();
        System.out.println(href +" "+older);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this

`Element pagination2 = document3.select("div.pagination a").get(0);`
this will give first link and

`Element pagination2 = document3.select("div.pagination a").get(1);`

this will give second link